# Ruby on Rails, passing parms getting nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create a new entry in my database in Rails 6 on Ruby 2.5.1

```
<%= form_for @Newevent do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :Group_Name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :groupnam %>
        <%= f.submit "Add New Event" %>
<% end %>
```

is my form and

```
    def create
        @Createevent = Event.new(params[:Newevent])

       if @Createevent.save
        redirect_to events_path, :notice => "Your event was saved"
       else
        render "new"
       end
    end
```

is my create, However, when I run this, the database entry just contains and nil at groupnam (yes I miss spelled that and can't be asked to fix it)

Comment: how your parameters are passing ? why you are not using strong parameters ?

Comment: You must use strong parameters, mass assignment like `new(params...)` is not possible from params.

Comment: Why can't you be asked to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This code has multiple issues:

1. The name of the parameters key is not dictated by the name of the instance variable that you pass to `form_for`. In Ruby methods don't actually know the name of the the variable you're passing as parameters. Instead Rails decides that by calling [`object.to_model.model_name.param_key`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-c-param_key) on the object you pass. This is based on the name of the class so the parameters are nested in `params[:event]`. The line `@Createevent = Event.new(params[:Newevent])` is actually calling `@Createevent = Event.new(nil)`.
2. You're not whitelisting the parameters for mass assignment. Since Rails 4 came out you are required to [use strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) to whitelist incoming parameters.  If you changed the above mentioned line to `@Createevent = Event.new(params[:event])` Rails will raise a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` exception.
3. Your naming is just plain bad to the point where its causing bugs. Ruby is a [language with strong conventions](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide). In Ruby everything except constants should be `snake_case`. That includes attributes, methods and variable names. [In ActiveRecord table names and column names should also be snake_case.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions) I can't really see why you feel like you need to prefix your instance variables with `@New..` and `@Create...` and that will actually cause an error when you call `render "new"`. You also have use `:Group_Name` for the label and `:group_nam` for the input - thats an accessiblity issue as screen readers won't be able to link the two. The misspelling also is an open invitation for future bugs.

The corrected code should look like:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_parameters)
    if @event.save
      redirect_to events_path, notice: "Your event was saved"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

  # whitelist the parameters for mass assignment
  def event_params
    params.require(:event)
          .permit(:group_name)
  end
end
```

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :group_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :group_name %>
  <%= f.submit "Add New Event" %>
<% end %>
```